# Calling showInfoWindow() for second time does not update the info window

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

Here's the thing:
I have a map with markers on it (managed by a ClusterManager) and I am showing an info window each time they are clicked. I am also fetching their address at the time they are clicked, so once I get it, I call showInfoWindow() on the marker again in order to update it. Problem is that the address won't show up in the info window. Here is my InfoWindowAdapter (I have two views according to the type of the marker that is clicked):

```
class CabinetInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    public CabinetInfoWindowAdapter () {

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // Use the default info window frame
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        Cabinet cabinet = clickedCabinetMarker.getCabinet();
        Log.i("fttxgr", "info contents, cabinet type: " + cabinet.getType().toString());

        switch (cabinet.getType()) {
            case ADSL:
            case VDSL:
                return getCabinetView(cabinet, marker);

            case DSLAM:
                return getDslamView(cabinet, marker);

            default: return null;
        }
    }

    private final View getCabinetView (final Cabinet cabinet, final Marker marker) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cabinet_info_window, null);

        TextView cabinetId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_id);
        TextView cabinetType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_type);
        TextView cabinetAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_address);
        TextView cabinetCoordinates = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_coordinates);
        TextView cabinetUserNick = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_user_nick);
        ImageView cabinetImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cabinet_image);
        View header = view.findViewById(R.id.header);

        cabinetId.setText (cabinet.getId() + " - " +  cabinet.getCabinetNumber());
        cabinetType.setText (cabinet.getType().toString());

        switch (cabinet.getType()) {
            case ADSL:
                header.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.adsl_red));
                break;
            case VDSL:
                header.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vdsl_green));
                break;
        }

        cabinetCoordinates.setText(cabinet.getCoordinates().toString());

        if (cabinet.getImage() == null) {
            loadCabinetImage(marker);
        } else {
            cabinetImage.setImageBitmap(cabinet.getImage());
        }

        if (cabinet.getUserNick() == null) {
            loadCabinetUserNick(cabinet, cabinet.getUserId(), cabinet.getmUserSite(), marker);
        } else {
            cabinetUserNick.setText("Added by user: " + cabinet.getUserNick());
        }

        if (cabinet.getAddress() == null) {
            loadCabinetAddress(cabinet.getCoordinates().latitude,
                    cabinet.getCoordinates().longitude, marker);
        } else {
            cabinetAddress.setText("Address: " + cabinet.getAddress());
        }

        return view;
    }

    private final View getDslamView (final Cabinet cabinet, final Marker marker) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dslam_info_window, null);

        TextView dslamId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dslam_id);
        TextView dslamAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.dslam_address);
        TextView dslamCoordinates = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.dslam_coordinates);

        dslamId.setText(cabinet.getId() + " - " + cabinet.getCabinetNumber());
        dslamCoordinates.setText(cabinet.getCoordinates().toString());

        if (cabinet.getAddress() == null) {
            Log.i("fttxgr", "address is null");
            loadCabinetAddress(cabinet.getCoordinates().latitude,
                    cabinet.getCoordinates().longitude, marker);
        } else {
            Log.i("fttxgr", "address is there: " + cabinet.getAddress());
            dslamAddress.setText("Address: " + cabinet.getAddress());
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

And the loadCabinetAddress() function:

```
private void loadCabinetAddress (final double lat, final double lng, final Marker marker) {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

        String concat = "" +
                ((address != null) ? address : "") + " - " +
                ((city != null) ? city : "") + " - " +
                ((country != null) ? country : "") + " - " +
                ((postalCode != null) ? postalCode : "");

        clickedCabinetMarker.getCabinet().setAddress(concat);
        Log.i("fttxgr", "address loaded, showing info window again");
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All the logs indicate that everything goes as expected. So why isn't the info window being updating properly?

P.S. The funny thing is that for the first view (the one returned by getCabinetView()), the update is working! But I also load an image and a user nickname asynchronously, and I call showInfoWindow() three times to update them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the ***`setOnClusterItemClickListener`*** method if you want to put the infowindow for each item in the cluster of if you want to put a single inforwindow for the whole cluster you can create it using the ***`setOnClusterClickListener`*** method instead of doing all this heavy lifting.

Create a ClusterManager and set the info window using the adapter:

```
ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterMgr = new ClusterManager<MarkerItem>(context, map);
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(clusterMgr.getMarkerManager());
```

Create `infowindowadapter` for one of them:

```
clusterMgr.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterForItems());
```

Final piece is mapping the raw Marker object that you'll receive in your custom InfoWindowAdapter's callback to the ClusterItem object(s) that you added to the map in the first place. This can be achieved using the onClusterClick and onClusterItemClick listeners, as follows:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterMgr);
clusterMgr.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new OnClusterItemClickListener<MarkerItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MarkerItem item) {
        clickedClusterItem = item;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have done all this linking, the info windows show up, it's just that they don't get updated when I call showInfoWindow() again.